# Function that storages variables from a list automatically, in another function

Tags: r, function, subset, name-value

For example I'd like to storage my variables only in f() function with the function `setObj(argument)`, whose argument is a list with a,b,c,d fields, for example.

```
   f<-function(x){
  setObj(argument=x)
  (a+b+c+d)/4
}
```

So I can call my variables with their names, without subsetting from the list.

Thank you

Comment: given x is a list, a data frame, or an integer you can use function `with()` to call the varibales directly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for `with`:

```
f<-function(x){
  with(x,
   (a+b+c+d)/4
  )
}


f(list(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4))
[1] 2.5
```

Comment: Thank you James it works. I also solved with attach(setObj())

Comment: @GianlucaPietronigro If you use `attach`, make sure to use `detach()` otherwise your environment can get pretty messed up. Better to avoid `attach()` altogether.